Подсчёт значений генератора c условием
Иногда требуется подсчитать количество значений генератора, которые отвечают какому-то условию. Есть два способа это сделать: sum(1 for ... if условие) и sum(условие for ...). Второй пользуется тем, что в арифметике False отображается в ноль, а True в единицу. Так что оба варианта считают одно и то же. Какой предпочитаете вы и почему?
Например тривиальный способ подсчёта количества делителей числа:
n = 100

s1 = sum(1 for i in range(1, n + 1) if n % i == 0)

s2 = sum(n % i == 0 for i in range(1, n + 1))

P.S. Вопрос про язык, не про алгоритм. Не предлагайте сосчитать делители по другому, быстрее.

Большое спасибо за вопрос! Я использовал второй вариант, так как первый мне просто в голову не пришел. Но, после Вашего вопроса, я так же как и CrazyElf , прикинул время выполнения и, о Боже мой, вот такой результат. Буду знать. Плюсую и вопрос и ответ.

@AlexeyTrukhanov Но вообще тут будет зависеть от того, какой процент элементов отсеивается условием. Если небольшой, то разницы почти не будет. А вот если отсев сильный, то разница между вариантами должна быть большая.

@VladimirBogdanov, спасибо! Вы подали идею вопроса, а это дорогого стоит.

По моим подсчётам получается второй вариант работает на 20% медленнее (при данном конкретном условии отсева чисел).
import time

n = 10_000_000

t = time.time()
s1 = sum(1 for i in range(1, n + 1) if n % i == 0)
print(time.time() - t)
# 1.008479356765747

t = time.time()
s2 = sum(n % i == 0 for i in range(1, n + 1))
print(time.time() - t)
# 1.2111566066741943

Я даже могу предположить - почему.

Число циклов - одинаковое
Проверка на остаток от деления - одинаковое число раз

Что же разное? А разное - количество элементов, которые выдаёт генератор, который дёргается функцией sum через итератор. Вот, видимо, большее кол-во элементов, пропускаемое через yield (и через sum!) и даёт некоторое замедление.
Я как обычно и через dis посмотрел.
Кусочек от первого варианта:
              8 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (n)
             10 LOAD_FAST                1 (i)
             12 BINARY_MODULO
             14 LOAD_CONST               0 (0)
             16 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             18 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE        2 (to 4)
             20 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
             22 YIELD_VALUE

Кусочек от второго варианта:
              6 STORE_FAST               1 (i)
              8 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (n)
             10 LOAD_FAST                1 (i)
             12 BINARY_MODULO
             14 LOAD_CONST               0 (0)
             16 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             18 YIELD_VALUE

Как видим, в первом варианте действительно YIELD_VALUE работает не на каждый элемент, а во втором на каждый.
P.S. Если почти все элементы в итоге пройдут через фильтр, то первый вариант будет работать медленнее из-за "лишней" инструкции перехода по условию POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE (переход при этом не происходит, но тестируется условие перехода). По идее эта разница не должна быть большой. Но тесты показывают 6-7% разницы.

Это верно, если много False, второй тормозит. Держите плюсик. А есть ещё две причины не использовать второй способ.

@StanislavVolodarskiy Интересно, но пока у меня нет гипотез. Если бы данные превращались в список перед суммированием, то тупо могла бы кончиться память, например. Но в данном случае этого вроде бы не происходит.

Подсчёт непустых строк: sum(1 for s in seq if s) против sum(s for s in seq). if s - канонический способ проверки непустоты строки/коллекции. Второй синтаксис не работает, так как не знает что s надо привести к bool.

@StanislavVolodarskiy Ну это уже не совсем исходная задача )  Кстати, при векторных способах вычисления, через тот же Numpy, и проще и выгоднее как-раз второй способ использовать. Если шире на всё это смотреть.

И ещё логические операторы в Питоне могу возвращать не True/False а число например. В if это не заметно, во втором варианте будет сюрприз.

@StanislavVolodarskiy Ну это вы докапываетесь уже, мне кажется. Извините )  Так то да, но с конкретными условиями, такими как в вопросе, проблем не будет.

Перезамерил время, повторив каждую операцию по 100 раз и выбрав лучшее время, т.к. однократный замер сильно зависит от сиюминутной загрузки компа. Разница в производительности получилась еще хуже: 31 против 54 условных единиц времени. Т.е. первый вариант быстрее аж на 43%. Вот тебе и перестановка мест слагаемых!

Я буду вести счёт. Начнём:
Краткость (0-1)
Второй вариант короче. Если вы спешите это важно. Это объективный критерий.
Ясность (0.5-1.5)
Оба варианта примерно наравне.
sum(1 for i in range(1, n + 1) if n % i == 0). Зачем складывать единички? Чтобы что-то сосчитать? Обычно для подсчётов есть специальная функция: что-нибудь с названием count. Но в Питоне она отсутствует, приходится считать единицы. Надо привыкнуть.
sum(n % i == 0 for i in range(1, n + 1)) тоже требует напряжения ума: надо понять что результат выражения булев, знать что булевы значения отображаются в целые числа так что сумма этих чисел будет равна количеству истинных значений. В общем ничья.
Хрупкость кода (1.5-1.5)
Второй вариант более хрупкий. Если вы возьмётесь считать непустые строки в списке, то получится такой код:
def s1(seq):
    return sum(1 for s in seq if s)

def s2(seq):
    return sum(s for s in seq)


print(s1(['', 'a', 'ab']))
print(s2(['', 'a', 'ab']))

Первый вариант сработает, второй упадёт при попытке сложить число и строку. Его надо исправить
так: sum(bool(s) for s in seq) или
так: sum(s != '' for s in seq) или
так: sum(len(s) != 0 for s in seq) или
так: sum(map(bool, seq)).
Или если вы решите написать функцию count для предиката:
def count1(seq, pred):
    return sum(1 for v in seq if pred(v))


def count2(seq, pred):
    return sum(pred(v) for v in seq)

Второй вариант снова более хрупкий. Питон разрешает в логических выражениях вместо True/False использовать другие значения. Например 42 or x != y вернёт 42. Так что count2 лучшее переписать
так: sum(bool(pred(v)) for v in seq) или
так: sum(map(lambda v: bool(pred(v)), seq)).
Производительность (2-2)
В соседнем ответе производительность разобрана на уровне ассемблера. Поставьте ему плюсик.
NB Я измерял на CPython 3.12. На других версиях результаты могут различаться.
Если коротко, то второй вариант тратит время складывая нули, первый вариант тратит время на условный переход, которого нет во втором. В среднем первый быстрее, но преимущество растворяется на фоне времени вычисления предиката.
Первый вариант быстрее, если количество True мало, а последовательность длинна:
from time import perf_counter

n = 100_000_000

start = perf_counter()
print(sum(1 for i in range(1, n + 1) if n % i == 0), perf_counter() - start)

start = perf_counter()
print(sum(n % i == 0 for i in range(1, n + 1)), perf_counter() - start)

Первый вариант на 28% быстрее второго:

$ python benchmark.py
81 5.596365669043735
81 7.764751962851733


Напротив, первый вариант медленнее если почти все значения – True:
from time import perf_counter

n = 100_000_000

start = perf_counter()
print(sum(1 for i in range(1, n + 1) if n % i != 0), perf_counter() - start)

start = perf_counter()
print(sum(n % i != 0 for i in range(1, n + 1)), perf_counter() - start)

Теперь уже второй вариант быстрее первого на 7%:

$ python benchmark.py
99999919 8.247191620990634
99999919 7.672776157036424


Я разделил очко поровну между вариантами, хотя первый имеет преимущество, пусть не очень большое. Но для кого-то это важно, имейте в виду.
Итоги
По очкам паритет, но если бы у меня было дополнительное очко, я бы отдал его первому варианту. Краткость меня мало волнует, а вот хрупкость второго варианта может приводить к неприятным ошибкам. И производительность в среднем немного лучше у первого варианта.

"первый вариант тратит лишнее время проверяя условия" ну, опять же - смотря какое условие. Если что-то для этого вычисляется, как в вопросе, так это вычисление происходит в обоих вариантах. Единственное, что делает первый вариант сверх того, что делает второй - это условный переход уже по готовому вычисленному значению. Если переходы почти отсутствуют, то видимо эта проверка и съедает дополнительное время. Но очень немного, по идее. Я даже и что 7% удивлён, много как-то. Это же чуть ли не один такт процессора сама проверка должна быть всего лишь, если я правильно помню. Откуда 7% то.

@CrazyElf, я имел ввиду инструкцию условного перехода. Проверьте у себя. Я получил стабильные 7%. Если вы увидите ошибку будет хорошо.

@CrazyElf, я поправил формулировку. Спасибо!

Я получил у себя 6% и добавил это в свой ответ с вашего позволения )  Там формулировку запаришься формулировать. Перехода то на самом деле нет. Но есть тест на условие перехода ))

@CrazyElf, позволяю конечно, могли бы не упоминать. Результат неожиданный, но что есть то есть.
